# How to alter a list item of a list

Tags: c#, list

I want to alter the items of a list, which they are lists too.

I tried:

```
for (int i = pChain.Count -1; i> 0; i --)
{
    List<String> item = pChain[i];
    item = item.RemoveSequentialRepeats().ToList();
}
```

Where the `RemoveSequentialRepeats` is a static function like:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> RemoveSequentialRepeats<T>(
     this IEnumerable<T> source) ....
```

As I trace the code, the function changes the list and removes the consecutive repeated items, but it is not stored in the main list `pChain`. Do I do something wrong?

Comment: `pChain[i] = pChain[i].RemoveSequentialRepeats().ToList();` - assign back the changed item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your example, it appears the RemoveSequentialReapeats doesn't edit the list but creates a new one instead. So, you're assigning a new value to item, and pChain doesn't update and remains with the original list. What you should do is add the line

```
pChain[i] = item;
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problem you've to assign back result from `Linq` statement to `pChain`.

```
pChain[i] = item;
```

Code can be even simplified and make it one liner code.

```
pChain = pChain.Select(li=> li.Select(item=>item.RemoveSequentialRepeats()).ToList());
```

Comment: It gives a conversion error from list<string> to list<string>

Comment: there was a missing brace, fixed now.